# Some misunderstanding on the Security Proof with Oracle

Tags: cryptanalysis, provable-security

I have a question about the security proof.
Suppose that I proved the following relations.
That is, I proved that $Adv_A \le Adv_A^{O} \le Adv_B$, where A,B are some cryptographic schemes and O is an oracle.
I also suppose that the oracle O has a very strong property. For example, the O can solve DLP in polynomial time.

On the other hand, there is an attacker $\mathcal{A}$ which can break the scheme A. That is, $Adv_A$ is not negligible in the security parameter.

Even though $Adv_B$ is also non-negligible, but we do not have the oracle O. In this setup, how to break the scheme B using $\mathcal{A}$?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look in more details the proof of the inequality $Adv^{O}_A \leq  Adv_B$.

The proof will give you explicitly how to construct $\mathcal{B}$ from $\mathcal{A}^O$. It should be written how to simulate the experiment with $A$
and the powerful oracle $O$, by only having interaction with the experiment with $B$.
And how to use the output of $\mathcal{A}$ to win the game against $B$.

Comment: You mean that it depends on how to construct the game? I do not have the concrete example. I am just curious about this case.

Comment: No it depends about your proof about the inequality work.

Comment: Thanks. As I understood, sometimes B is broken, and sometimes B is still secure. Is there an example?

Comment: No, if A is broken then B is also broken, but the way to Break B depends about the proof of the inequality (and the way to break A).

Comment: Thanks. I will find some examples.